# Runnable interface and related objects

Tags: java

```
public Runnable updater = new Runnable() 
    {   
        @Override
        public void run() {
         obj.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    };
```

I am new to java, I read that codesnip and wonder when we need such an updater or a class that implements the Runnable interface.
To call that updater, they do this

```
handler = new Handler();
handler.post(updater);
```

I don't understand the underlying logic of this.

Comment: I would guess that `Handler` instance has a queue where we can lineup our `Runnable` instances using a call to `post` method. Then `Handler` could have a dedicated `thread` which gets `Runnable` instance from the queue and calls `runnable.run()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know the rest of the context, but in that way you select different "behaviours" in your object `Handler`. As I don't know the context of the code where you saw this example, I'll try to explain it with different classes and methods:

Say, for instance that you want to be able to perform different behaviours in the same piece of code, so you could create new behaviours or select from an existing one, you could have:

```
class Operation {

    Runnable operation = null;

    private int result;
    private int op1;
    private int op2;

    public Example(int op1, int op2) {
        this.op1 = op1;
        this.op2 = op2;
    }

    // ... more code ...

    Runnable sum = new Runnable() {
        public void run() { result = op1 + op2; }
    }

    Runnable minus = new Runnable() {
        public void run() { result = op1 - op2; }
    }

    // ... more code ...

    public void selectBehaviour(String behaviourName) {

        // ... more code ...

        // select behaviour
        if("SUM".equals(behaviourName)) {
            operation = sum;
        } else if("MINUS".equals(behaviourName)) {
            operation = minus;
        } else {
            // ... more code ...
        }

    }

    public void perform() {
        operation.run();
    }

    int getResult() {
        return result;
    }
}
```

This case is so common that in Java 8 you will be able to write the code you posted in this way:

```
public Runnable updater = () -> { obj.notifyDataSetChanged(); }
```

which is way less verbose.